# NGINX keep redirects to the old site with no redirect config

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have created a working AWS EC2 instance for hosting a WordPress site, and then I create an image from that instance.

Just tried creating another instance using that image, changed the Nginx config but it always redirects to the first instance site there’s no redirect config whatsoever on the `sites-available` Nginx config. I did use certbot for handling the HTTP to HTTPS redirection on the first instance.

How can I found what’s causing the redirection?

Comment: you said it is redirecting or you mean it is displaying the same content ?

Comment: As I understand from your question it is connecting to the same database that is why it is displaying the same content of the first site, please correct me if misunderstood otherwise I can post this as an answer

Comment: Always test these things in a incognito browser or a private window of your browser

Comment: The redirect might be coming from WordPress. The website address you type in the config page, would cause it to redirect to there. You would need to login to the second server and manually edit the DB entry to stop the redirect.